# Regular expression to format data in notepad++

Tags: regex, csv, notepad++

After editing  CSV file with notepad++ I need to correct CSV format.

Data in notepad++

```
8,11.6 laptop review
9,1280 1024 desktop
10,1280 x 1024 desktop
11,1280 x 1024 desktop background
12,1280 x 1024 desktop wallpaper
```

I want it in this manner

```
8,"11.6 laptop review"
9,"1280 1024 desktop"
10,"1280 x 1024 desktop"
11,"1280 x 1024 desktop background"
12,"1280 x 1024 desktop wallpaper"
```

And also in this manner

```
"8","11.6 laptop review"
"9","1280 1024 desktop"
"10","1280 x 1024 desktop"
"11","1280 x 1024 desktop background"
"12","1280 x 1024 desktop wallpaper"
```

Any regular expression?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Find: **`,(.+)\r?\n`**

Replace with: **`,\"\1\"\n`**

[image]

---

For the latter case, you can do:

Find: **`(.+),(.+)\r?\n`**

Replace with: **`\"\1\",\"\2\"\n`**

Comment: This will remove the `\r` if it's present in the string. Also, it isn't mandatory to escape the quotes

Answer (score 0):

I'd do:

Find What: `^([^,]+),(.+)$`
Replace with: `"$1","$2"`

then clic on <kbd>Replace All</kbd>.

`[^,]+` means one or more characters that is not a comma.